# Assign a unique ID to each column that has the same unique characters

Tags: r

I have a list of strings, which looks like this:

```
"kkv", "ll27", "g998", "g98", "kv"
```

I'd like to assign a unique ID to each string which has the same characters, regardless of its length. For example, "kkv" and "kv" and "g998" and "g98" would have the same ID.

EDIT: Sorry, I should say the exact same unique characters. So "kkv" and "kv" would have the same ID, but "kv" and "kv1" would not.

Here's a table with the output I'd like:

```
"kkv"  1
"ll27" 2
"g998" 3
"g98"  3
"kv"   1
```

Comment: Is it based on the first letter?  In that case `split(v1, substr(v1, 1,1))`

Comment: What if you have "kv" and "g98" in the same string?

Comment: No, it's based on having the same unique characters. "kkv" and "kv" have the same unique characters, so they would have the same ID.

Comment: Sorry, I should say the exact same unique characters. So "kkv" and "kv" would have the same ID, but "kv" and "kv1" would not.

Comment: May be you need to `strsplit` the strings and get the unique elements

Comment: Try `split(v1,sapply(strsplit(v1, ''), function(x) paste(unique(x),collapse='')))`

Comment: Thanks for the expected output.  But, you have to understand that we cannot post a solution without showing the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sorted string containing one of each letter in the original string forms such an identifier:

```
y <- c('vkk', 'kkv', 'll27', 'g998', 'g98', 'kv')
sapply(strsplit(y, ''), function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse=''))
## [1] "kv"  "kv"  "27l" "89g" "89g" "kv"
```

To turn these into numbers, you can use a factor:

```
z <- sapply(strsplit(y, ''), function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse=''))
as.numeric(factor(z))
## [1] 3 3 1 2 2 3
```

Comment: Assigning your result to `z`, then `match(z,unique(z))` or similar to match OP's desired output.